# Add a default value in group by select in case a specific value is not present

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table:

```
code | value | req_date
```

and the following query:

```
select code, sum(value) sums, req_date from TABLE
                group by code,req_date
```

Normally codes "0" and "30" should be present, anyway I'd like to make so that, if not present, the following default records

```
"0" | 0 | <date>
"30"| 0 | <date>
```

appear. Possible?

Comment: What kind of date do you wait in default records? Curent date, every date from your table, every date for period or string with "<date>"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after a default value for 0 and 30, then unioning your table to additional rows with the default data and then grouping the whole lot should work:

```
SELECT
    code
    ,SUM(value) sums
    ,req_date
FROM
(

    SELECT
      code
      ,value
      ,req_date 
    FROM TABLE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      '30' AS code
      ,0 AS value
      ,SYSDATE AS req_date --default date here

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      '0' AS code
      ,0 AS value
      ,SYSDATE AS req_date --default date here
) unionTable

GROUP BY code
,req_date
```

Answer (score 0):

normally for this type of problem you would start with a list of all possible combinations and left join from that to your data.

generally these fall into two groups of problem, one where you only want dates that appear somewhere in your data and the other where you create a new table with all possible dates in it to start with.

I will assume that you are okay only having the dates you already have:

```
select 
    dc.code
    , sum(value) sums
    , dc.req_date 
from
    (select 
        * 
    from 
        (select distinct
            code
        from 
            TABLE) as codes --this gets lis to fpossible codes
        CROSS JOIN --this creates all possible combinations of codes and dates
        (select distinct
            req_date
        from
            table
            ) as dates --this is all possible dates
        ) as dc
    left outer join table as t
        on dc.req_date = t.req_date
        amd dc.code = t.code
group by 
    code
    ,req_date
```